# memory management error in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, memory-management, reference

I have doubts about the following test snippet. I use a Node pointer to point the node instance returned by function test2. Why the delete failed ?

Any comments would be appreciated. thanks!

```
struct Node
{
    int a;
};
Node& test2(Node &n)
{
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->a = n.a + 5;
    return *p;
}
Node* test3(Node &n)
{
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->a = n.a + 5;
    return p;
}
int main()
{
    Node m;
    m.a = 12;
    Node n = test2(m);
    Node *x = test3(n);
    cout << m.a << ";" << n.a << ";" << x->a << endl;
    delete x;  //OK
    x = &n;
    delete x;  //Error
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
    Node n = test2(m);
```

`n` is not a reference to the `Node` created by `test2`.  It is a *copy* of it.  The `Node` created by `test2` is leaked.  You need:

```
    Node& n = test2(m);
```

As an aside:  I assume this is an exercise to understand references and pointers.  For a real program, you would always want to write:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> test4(const Node& n)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> result{new Node};
    result->a = n.a + 5;
    return result;
}
```

or even better:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> test4(const Node& n)
{
    auto result = std::make_unique<Node>();
    result->a = n.a + 5;
    return result;
}
```

With either of these solutions, you don't need to bother about deleting the allocated `Node` - the compiler will do that for you when the unique_ptr in your calling code goes out of scope.

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain why?  (I'd like to improve the answer if possible).

Comment: I'd like to upvote your comment. But I don't know why the number turns to negative when I click the up arrow...

Comment: Thank you so much for your such a nice explain!

Answer (score 1):

`test2` returns a reference of a `Node` object that's copied (or moved) to `n` because `n` is not a reference.
This object now resides on the stack, calling `delete` on objects on the stack is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the delete failed ?

Here

```
x = &n;
delete x;  //Error
```

you are assigning an address of a local variable

```
Node n = test2(m);
```

which can't (neither needs to) be handled by `delete`.

Comment: Thank you for your explain!